# Font in footer changes despite footer already having CSS class declared

Tags: html, css

I have a design which uses DIV with flex, at https://jsfiddle.net/1s2mpba6/, but the main problem here relates to use of webfonts, one area, despite not having a webfont, seems to have been replaced even though the body font is used.

I get this when it should be Helvetica:
[image: Font-face]

These are the areas of the HTML and CSS which seem to be problematic:

```css
header.california-m {
  background-color: #B22222;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 840px;
}

footer.california-m {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 840px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

footer.california-m h2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Fabriga Regular;
  src: url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.eot?v=1.1.0");
  src: url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.eot?#iefix&v=1.1.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.woff2?v=1.1.0") format("woff2"), url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.woff?v=1.1.0") format("woff"), url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.ttf?v=1.1.0") format("truetype"), url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Regular.svg?v=1.1.0#Regular") format("svg");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Fabriga Medium;
  src: url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.eot?v=1.1.0");
  src: url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.eot?#iefix&v=1.1.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.woff2?v=1.1.0") format("woff2"), url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.woff?v=1.1.0") format("woff"), url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.ttf?v=1.1.0") format("truetype"), url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATFabriga-Medium.svg?v=1.1.0#Medium") format("svg");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ATVFabriga;
  src: url("https://c.atcdn.co.uk/fonts/ATVFabriga.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

.columns-vehicleresult+h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: Fabriga Regular, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.columns-vehicleresult .column p.autog1 {
  font-family: Fabriga Regular, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.columns-vehicleresult .column p.autog1 b {
  line-height: 16px;
}

.atc-type-picanto {
  font-family: ATVFabriga, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<footer class="california-m">
  <h2>1 Anytown Road, Anytown 1</h2>
  <h2>&phone; 555 0100</h2>
</footer>
```

However, I've not used a font-family for header or footer so why is this only happening to the footer and what do I need to fix?

Functionally, it works well, aesthetically, it's a small thing to fix, advice welcomed!

It should be in Helvetica as with the rest of the text for body declared in CSS, apart from the .columns-vehicle-result which use a webfont.

Comment: The content of your footer are two `h2` elements, and the rule with selector `.columns-vehicleresult + h1, h2, h3` applies to those. (Are you not aware of the difference between `.foo .bar, .baz` and `.foo .bar, .foo .baz` ...?)

Comment: @CBroe: Thank you for pointing it out. I removed the plus sign but it's still showing in the same font.

Comment: Why remove the plus sign? If the formatting of that rule is supposed to only apply to headline elements that immediately follow a `.columns-vehicleresult`, for all three of those headline levels - then this would need to become `.columns-vehicleresult + h1, .columns-vehicleresult + h2, .columns-vehicleresult + h3`

Comment: @CBroe: Brain fog for a second there. Your answer is the right one but I can't tick it as accepted for some reason, only upvote. Forgot I'd applied it to all by not using the class and plus sign for each. Now I get it.

Comment: This being a Q&A site, only answers can be accepted, not the comments from the discussion. I added an answer comprised of the content of the above comments.

Answer (score 2):

The content of your footer are two h2 elements, and the rule with selector `.columns-vehicleresult + h1, h2, h3` applies to those.

If the formatting of that rule is supposed to only apply to headline elements that immediately follow a `.columns-vehicleresult`, for all three of those headline levels - then this would need to become

```
.columns-vehicleresult + h1, .columns-vehicleresult + h2, .columns-vehicleresult + h3 { }
```